# Comparing elements of two arrays

Tags: java, arrays, static-methods, boolean-expression

My method accepts two arrays of integers and returns `true` if

1. The arrays are the same length and
2. each a.element is less than the b.element of the same index.

It works for all my test cases except when `int[] a = {1, 2, 3}` and `int[] b = {4, 5, 1}`. It returns true even though `a[2] > b[2]`. The `digitDifference` check isn't working correctly but I can't see the error.

```
public static boolean allLess(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int i = 0;
    boolean sameLength = (a.length == b.length);
    boolean digitDifference = (a[i] < b[i]);
    for (i = 0; i <= a.length - 1; i++) {}
    return (sameLength && digitDifference);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loop does nothing, so you are only comparing the elements in the first index of the arrays.

Your code should look something like this :

```
public static boolean allLess(int[] a, int[] b) {
    boolean sameLength = (a.length == b.length);
    if (!sameLength)
        return false;
    boolean digitDifference = true;
    for (int i = 0; i <= a.length - 1 && digitDifference; i++) {
        digitDifference = (a[i] < b[i]);
    }
    return digitDifference;
}
```

Now the for loop compares each pair of elements having the same index, and terminates once it finds a pair that violates your requirement that `(a[i] < b[i])`.

Another equivalent implementation without the flags :

```
public static boolean allLess(int[] a, int[] b) {
    if (a.length != b.length)
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i <= a.length - 1; i++) {
        if (a[i] >= b[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your method only compares the first element in each array - the comparison is done outside the `for` loop (which is empty!) instead of inside it. Move it there, and you should be OK.

It's worth noting that using the early return idiom would help produce much easier to read code in this scenario, as you don't need to continue "dragging" the current state with you, just fail-fast when one of the conditions is broken:

```
public static boolean allLess(int[] a, int[] b) {
    if (a.length != b.length) {
        return false;
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= a.length - 1; i++) {
        if (a[i] >= b[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. My original schema used an "if" and then a for loop but I was trying to use that "boolean Zen" to reduce the code as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

`digitDifference` is initialized before the loop, and compare the first elements of both arrays, since `i`'s value is 0 at this point. You never compare the other elements of the array. The comparison must be done **inside** the loop.

BTW, your loop body doesn't even have a single instruction.

Answer (score 2):

You have a check to compare the length of both arrays, but you only act upon it at the end of the method. Java, like any other language allows you to have multiple return statements in a method, so my suggestion would be to return from the method as soon as you perform the check:

```
if (a.length != b.length)
   return false;
```

Second, the `digitDifference` statement in your code is only evaluated once, with the first elements in your arrays. I believe, you wanted the for-loop to perform the comparison multiple times on each element in the array, however, you left the body of the loop empty.

```
for (i = 0; i <= a.length - 1; i++) {
    if(a[i] >= b[i])
       return false;
}
```

Again, my suggestion is to return as soon as you find that one of the elements breach you constraint. And just have a `return true;` after the for-loop, which will indicate that all of the elements satisfy the constraint `a[i] >= b[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

```java
List<String> list1 = List.of("Banana", "Watermelon", "Carrot");
List<String> list2 = List.of("Apple", "Plum", "Orange");
       
System.out.println(list1.stream().anyMatch(list2::contains));
```

Output: false

```java
List<String> list1 = List.of("Banana", "Watermelon", "Carrot");
List<String> list2 = List.of("Apple", "Plum", "Orange", "Watermelon");
       
System.out.println(list1.stream().anyMatch(list2::contains));
```

Output: true